# RSpec calls my slow test multiple times

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test an object in RSpec. There are multiple things I want to check before and after, so I followed the examples I found around the web and ended up with something like this:

```
describe Processor do
  before(:each) do
    # create some data in temp to run the test against
  end
  after(:each) do
    # wipe out the data we put in temp
  end

  let(:processor) { Processor.new }

  describe '#process' do
    subject { lambda { processor.process } }

    # it should actually perform the processing
    it { should change { count('...') }.from(0).to(1) }
    it { should change { count('...') }.from(0).to(2) }

    # it should leave some other things unaffected
    it { should_not change { count('...') } }
  end
end
```

This does work, but what I'm seeing is that both the `before()` code and `#process` are slow - and being executed by RSpec three times each.

Usually when you have a slow thing, people say "just mock it out", but this time, it's the very thing I am trying to test which is slow, so that would be pointless.

How can I avoid multiple calls to the subject of the test, in this situation where all the checks are of the before-and-after variety?

Comment: What does "check" actually mean?

Comment: Ok, I didn't need a synonym ;) I don't see `check1` defined. Is it defined within the code to be tested or within the `before` block?

Comment: It stands in for the actual check being done, the nature of which isn't really important. What's important is that it returns a value which is supposed to be 0 before the test and 1 after.

Comment: without knowing what's in those slow blocks (and therefore the meaning of the test) how can we say? after blocks are usually always a code smell.

Comment: I understand you don't want to show too much code, but if someone's asking you questions in the comments it usually means a bit of clarification is helpful, and notes should be added on pseudo code. Stick all the 3 `it` blocks into one `it` block and it should all just run once.

Comment: that would go against having a single assertion per test, which I don't think is generally a good idea.

Comment: @sevenseacat Multiple assertions per test is, I think, okay so long as they are highly cohesive, but it shouldn’t be done because of speed, it should be done because it makes sense.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall good point. But without the code, we can't really say in this case.

Comment: OK... I put some comments in before and after but I don't know if it will really help and the slowest thing is process() anyway. I can optimise before and after by running them before and after all instead of each.

Comment: @sevenseacat I agree, but without more code/clarification what else am I to say? It answers the question, I'll leave it in the comments, if someone has a better idea they can put it in as a proper answer.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see what code could be provided which would make the question any easier to understand... I'll add more comments, but I'm sort of hitting the limits here. Showing the real code isn't going to help much, it will just add clutter and introduce red herrings for people to peck at.

Comment: You can only really get them fast while keeping assertions in separate tests if your tests *only assert on the result* (which yours don’t because of `change`); though even then it’s risky and rarely worth it. Otherwise you have to combine them or suffer the speed (or make your actual code faster).

Answer (score 2):

before(:each) and after(:each) is a callback that's called before and after *each* spec, i.e. each 'it'. If you wish to do something before and after the outer 'describe' block, use before(:all) and after(:all).

See [rspec docs here (relishapp)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before%28%3aall%29-block-in-example-group).

(Note, however, that if you're using rspec with rails, using before/after(:all) will run outside of the regular cleanup of the database, which might lead to crap in your test db.)

Good luck!

Comment: The slowest thing here is the process() call, actually. I'm already in the middle of changing before/after to :all... of course, the problem is that now tests are cross-dependent, so I have to be really careful that the tests don't tread on each other if I do that.